# Using AWS Lambda to transform files on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a very simple scenario. 
I use Lambda to load multiple 100MB files from S3 (every 1-10 seconds a new file(s) land on s3), transform them (minor changes) and store them on a different S3 Bucket.

The problem in my Java program (running on AWS Lambda) is giving Memory overflow errors even though I allocated 1024MD RAM. I load the complete files in RAM. Not sue why this happens.

I have following questions:

1. Without filling my RAM, what is a good approach to read, transform and write 100MB files on S3 repeatedly and concurrently? Is Lambda a good choice for this case?
2. Why is my memory getting full even though I allocated 1024 memory through web UI?

Comment: I also want to do this. I have lost faith in databases and just want to store my application data in plain files on S3 (or something else file-centric).